# Set the width of a image in a new tab

Tags: html, css

What I want is a link in my text to a image. When u click on the link the image should open fullscreen on a new tab. I got so far that the image opens on a new tab, but it isn't fullscreen. My code looks like this:

```
<p>some text <a href="css/images/website.png" target="blank">website</a> and more text</p>
```

But if i click on the link it looks like the image get the height of the page, in my case:

```
img[Attributes Style] {
width: 918px;
height: 979px;
}
```

I want it to be something like this

```
img[Attributes Style] {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

I've tried

```
<a href="css/images/website.png" width="100%">website</a>
<a href="css/images/website.png" style="width: 100%;"></a>
```

but both dont work.
Have u guys any idea how I can do this?

This is the first time i ask something here, if i did something wrong I would like to hear it :)

Comment: You link to an image file, you can't apply any style there.

Comment: When you display an image in the browser, it's only the image. No CSS gets applied. You need to create a small HTML file with just an <img> element and the desired styles, and link to that from your main page.

Comment: You need to use Javascript to toggle a modal or box with the image on it. Check out "Owl Carousel" or you can google tutorials on how to create one by yourself using JavaScript.

Comment: @lukbl The window opens fullscreen, the image doesn't it. The image is only like 50% of the screen.

Comment: make a new html for your purpose, because you are opening a image source, not a html, you can't apply any style for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have no control over any style attributes, because the new tab is actually not an html page, but only the image by itself. You can on the other hand make a html page that's sole purpose is to show the styled image. Make your link something like `<a href = "bigImg.html?src=css/images/website.png">website</a>` and in `bigImg.html` you can use javascript or php to get the `src` of the image you want to load. In the css of `bigImg.html` style the image anyway you like.

Comment: This is a nice idee but it doesn't work for single page apps (like React, Angular, etc...) :(

Comment: @Berci it would still work the same way, it just opens a new tab. If you want to show the image in the current page you can use css already and style it however you like.